# DAO and DTO in struts 2 framework

Tags: orm, dao

My web project now requires dao and dto features. How do I use dao and dto?

Comment: dao is related to ORM layer and i assume you are already using DTO to transfer data from your action to jsp and reverse order

Answer (score 0):

DAO design pattern works with Data transfer object also known as value object. DTO is a java class with properties, getter and setter methods.